# Material pagination dropdown out of place

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

### Issue

I am currently implementing a `<mat-table>` with a `<mat-paginator>` attached to it. The only problem is that the dropdown for items per page is being offset to the left. For what seems like outside of the Bootstrap `container`.

Here is an image of what is happening. You can see the location of the dropdown and the location of the items are completely wrong.
[image: Offset]

---

### Code

My entire site is inside of a bootstrap container so my `app.component.html` basically looks like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container mt-3">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The page in questions is just a simple material table with the pagination added to the bottom.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <mat-table *ngIf="items" [dataSource]="items" matSort>

      <!-- ID Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Type </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.type}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Provider Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="provider">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Provider </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> <a href="https://eosauthority.com/account/{{row.provider}}" target="_blank">{{row.provider}}</a> </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="url">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> URL </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.url}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Color Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Country </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.country}} - <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{row.country | lowercase}}"></span> </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Color Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="updated_on">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Updated </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.updated_on}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['type', 'provider', 'url', 'country', 'updated_on']"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['type', 'provider', 'url', 'country', 'updated_on']">
      </mat-row>
    </mat-table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

It seems that some `css` are needed. Just try including in your `style.css` or `style.scss` the line

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Answer (score 4):

I can solve this problem finally =D We have known that some css code of Angular overwritten the original css code of the pagination which work with the **cdk-overlay-container**. That's why I have tried to copy the code out of the file **@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css** in my own css-File what has fixed the bug. Afterwards I have looked which components I really needed and that's it:

```
//Add this to your css/scss File
::ng-deep {
  .cdk-overlay-container,
  .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .cdk-overlay-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

  .cdk-overlay-pane {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Now you have the original pagination of Angular if you want a non transparent dropbox selection, add the following lines to **.cdk-overlay-pane**

```
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

Have you imported Material Pagination Module? If not then please import and try again. Thanks

Comment: I have imported it, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Can you share fiddle for that, because it's work fine on my end

Answer (score 0):

In most projects, be it boostrap-themed or material-themed, there is usually a theme folder, you would have files like `theme-variable.scss` and `theme.scss` for Bootstrap projects, while in material projects, you'd find `material-theme.css` or `material-theme.scss`.

The last two files are very important for angular-material components to be rendered properly, even after importing the modules responsible for the component, you need the files mentioned above.

After ensuring you have those two files, you want to import them in your `styles.css` file with this line: `@import './theme/material-theme.css';`

Once the above steps are taken, the table or whichever angular-material component will render properly.